# Report Builder (Digital Metaphors) add empty rows in details band until the end of page

Tags: ms-access, row, delphi-2006, reportbuilder

I am using ReportBuilder 10 in Delphi 2006 with an Access 2000 database. I am trying to create a report using a filtered query.

[Telerik Report : Starch line in Detail band or Add Empty rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070782/telerik-report-starch-line-in-detail-band-or-add-empty-rows)

[Repeat a vertical line on every page in Report Builder / SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106936/repeat-a-vertical-line-on-every-page-in-report-builder-ssrs)

Similar to the questions above, I am trying to add empty rows (or records) in the ReportBuilder's details band after the filtered query records. Until it fills the page. My details band is like an excel table and it can take 25 rows per page. If I have 30 records, the first page is good. But the second page will have 5 records. Then, a huge gap will appear between the details and footer bands. That looks bad.

I tried to search for this, but nothing comes up. Only the second link above. But no solution I can use was posted.

I hope I properly explained my problem to you guys. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know ReportBuilder well  enough to give specifics, but I suggest

1. Adding 25 blank rows to the report's query result. You should be able to do this using a series of UNION commands. Make sure any sorting actions place these at the end of the results.
2. Create a boolean variable `isBlankLine` that is updated for each line of the details as it is being evaluated for layout. This variable simply is set to true if the record is a blank line (one of the lines added in step 1.)
3. Create another boolean variable `isReportEnd` that is evaluated on the page footer. This is set to true if `isBlankLine` is true, otherwise it is set to  false.
4. Finally, for each detail line, suppress the line if `isReportEnd` is true.

This will allow the page to fill in with blank lines and suppress any additional pages. The only catch I can think of is that if the report ends with exactly 25 records, such that the first line of the next page will be a blank line, then your last page will be blank.